# Change git accounts - permission denied with old account

Tags: git, bash, github

I'm using a new Github account with a new username.

I have generated the SSH keys for the new acccount on my computer.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

When I try to push to a repo in the new account I get

```
    remote: Permission to "user name on new account"/repo.git denied to "user name on old account".
```

Do I have to change the username in Github somewhere?

Comment: Are you using ssh or https urls?

Comment: how did you try to push, show the command.

Comment: I'm using https urls. The commands I used - git init, git add ., git commit -m 'message', git remote add origin <github repo url>, git remote -v, git push -u origin master

Answer (score 2):

If you use wincred for credential.helper, git is storing your credentials in standard windows Credential Manager:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Just login to your old GitHub account, go to settings, SSH Keys and delete your key. Or delete the old private key from your machine. There's got to be another way to do this. But this is what worked for me.